# Vuejs - list item manipulation and verification per item

Tags: vue.js

The app receives a json list of items.

This list contains 4 elements:

- `id`
- `name`
- `code`
- `max_cost`

  ```
  data: { itemList: [
  {id: 0, name: 'Apple', code: '007', max_cost: 50},
  {id: 1, name: 'Pear', code: '008', max_cost: 25},
  {id: 2, name: 'Chees', code: '006', max_cost: 75}
  ], 
  }
  ```

Displaying the list is easy enough. As part of the display one must enter a cost for each item.

```
<ul v-for="item in itemList">
  <li >
    {{ item.name }}
    <input type="text" v-model="item.cost" value="25" v-on="change: verifyCost(item)">
  </li>
</ul>
```

The app must verify that the cost entered is less than or equal to the item's maximum cost. If the item's max cost is exceeded the app must set the cost to the maximum cost.

```
methods: {
verifyCost: function(item){
    if(item.cost >= item.max_cost){
    alert('Max cost exceeded');
    item.cost = item.max_cost;
  }      
},
```

},

Please see the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/daanjacobs/0ym20pye/6/

Thank you for any assistance, I am convinced it is something small that I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `v-on` syntax was incorrect.

wrong:

```
v-on="change: ..."
```

right:

```
v-on:change="..."
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Linusborg/0ym20pye/9/

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much.